# How to stop relaying in sendmail 8.14

Tags: sendmail

This is my sendmail version:

```
Version 8.14.4
 Compiled with: DNSMAP HESIOD HES_GETMAILHOST LDAPMAP LOG MAP_REGEX
                MATCHGECOS MILTER MIME7TO8 MIME8TO7 NAMED_BIND NETINET NETINET6
                NETUNIX NEWDB NIS PIPELINING SASLv2 SCANF SOCKETMAP STARTTLS
                TCPWRAPPERS USERDB USE_LDAP_INIT
Canonical name: dynawebs.net
 UUCP nodename: dynawebs.net
        a.k.a.: [xxxx9.226]

============ SYSTEM IDENTITY (after readcf) ============
      (short domain name) $w = xx
  (canonical domain name) $j = xx.net
         (subdomain name) $m = xx
              (node name) $k = xx.net
========================================================
```

and my relay is open to all right now (with user auth), and I am not sure why.
Maybe because I upgraded from a previous version.
Which files do I need to re-edit now, to make sure I block all relaying and only allow specific domains?

I already put in /etc/mail/access
`*.* REJECT`

but it doesn't seem to work.
My goal is only to allow my domains to block and right now the only thing that seems to work is for me to specifically put rejects in the /etc/mail/access
as in

```
154.50.50.40 REJECT
```

Comment: Could you include log entries generated by unwanted relay? Does your sendmail relay unwanted messages after SMTP AUTH? Modern sendmail configuration forbid relaying by default => You should find what makes your sendmail relay.

Comment: This question is not about programming and therefor off topic here. It might be on topic on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/)

Comment: tx for replying, here is the message ```Jul 17 07:23:51 dynawe sendmail[22835]: ruleset=check_relay, arg1=[101.200.124.147], arg2=101.200.124.147, relay=[101.200.124.147], reject=550 5.7.1 Access denied``` as you can see it is getting access denied, but that is only becuase I blocked the IP 101.x.x.x address from /etc/mail/access, otherwise it would successfully route it, and I don't know how to stop routing bu default.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will help, but I was having an issue getting sendmail to accept my config changes for exactly this issue

```
    *.* REJECT not working
```

until I ran sendmailconfig from the command line. IIRC, it compiles the access file and some others into it's config it uses.  Maybe my obscure solution is yours, albient a few years late :(